# Interpreting the way we choose partitions in the pumping lemma for CFLs

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

This question is referring to the Pumping Lemma for CFLs, namely:

> If $L$ is a CFL, there is a pumping length $p$ such that any string $z \in L$ of length $\geq p$ can be written as $z = uxwyz$, where $|xy| \geq 1$, $|vxy| \leq p$, and $\forall i ≥ 0, ux^iwy^iz \in L$.

Let's say we have a language consisting of $0$s and $1$s and we pick $x \in 0^*$ and $y \in 0^* \Rightarrow x = 0^k$ and $y = 0^l$, where $k+l \geq 1$. Does this mean that $k$ can be $0$ if $l \geq 1$? Does that make sense? (why did we choose a $k$ length of $x$ in the first place, then, if it's going to end up being null).

PS: I know I don't get to pick the decomposition. I'm talking about a particular case.

Comment: You *don't* get to pick $x,y$. The pumping lemma states that for each long enough $z$ there exists *some* decomposition $z = uxwyz$ satisfying the given properties. Not every decomposition satisfies these properties.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well I'm not talking about picking the decomposition. I;m talking about a particular case.

Comment: If $k = 0$ and $l \geq 1$ then $k + l \geq 1$, but I'm sure you already knew that. I suspect your real question is "why did we choose a $k$ length of $x$ in the first place", but there seems to be some context missing here.

Comment: Well, yeah thanks for reading between the lines there! That's actually my question? In what way, context? Could you be more specific, so I can improve it?

Comment: You have two questions in your post. One of them is where $k=0$ and $l \geq 1$ implies $k + l \geq 1$. I don't think you need us to answer this question. The other one is "(why did we choose a $k$ length of $x$ in the first place, then, if it's going to end up being null)". Since it was you who chose "a $k$ length of $x$", you should be the one answering this question. I suspect you were just copying somebody else's notes, and this is the context we are missing here.